# how to get a newmeric value from website using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I want to get the value 17,928.05 from below

17,928.05

```html
<span id="pt1:pt_r0:0:pt1:rgn1:0:pt1:rgn29:0:pt1:pcl1:it1::content" class="x25" theme="light">17,928.05</span>
```

I tried below code but it didn't work. any leads greatly appreciated.

int curbaltot=Integer.valueOf(<>.getAttribute("InnerText"));

System.out.println("Current Total Balance: "+curbaltot);

Comment: You'll get back a string from the .text() or getAttribute methods.  You'd convert via native language.  Maybe Float.parseFloat()... strip the comma out first.

Comment: _but it didn't work_: Do you see any error?

Comment: getting error as below      Cannot invoke "String.trim()" because "in" is null      float curbaltot=Float.parseFloat(th.CurrBalnTotal().getAttribute("InnerText"));

Comment: Try using `findElement` and `getText()` then parsing the `String` to `Float`. source: [get text from website: selenium](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-the-text-from-a-website-using-selenium) - Debomita Bhattacharjee.

Comment: thank you everyone for your thoughts.  issue is resolved by using below code  String curbaltot=th.CurrBalnTotal().getAttribute("innerHTML");
  Issue due to the synchronization.